# mybatis iterate through map and execute multiple select statements

Tags: java, mybatis

I would like to pass in a map and use mybatis to iterate through the map and execute multiple select statements and collect the results in a map. Is this possible? The below does an AND as one query.

```
<select id="populate" parameterType="Map" resultType="hashmap">
    <foreach collection="dataMap" index="key" item="value" open=""
        separator=" and " close="">
    select count(*) as countS from tabl where

        id LIKE #{key,jdbcType=VARCHAR} || '%'
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like as it is written will not work, the *%* must be part of the bound parameter. I would do something like this:

```
<bind name="currentKey" value = 'key + "%"' />
id LIKE #{currentKey,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```

**Edit**: About the LIKE, I've given the most common answer, I have found other posts stating your method works and that it may even be better regarding security (injection) since the % is not part of bound parameter.

Is the % to be considered as part of the string or as operator?

Does it yield the same? Same results? Same performance? (if performance could be expected from a LIKE).

If there is 2 keys in the parameter map, then produced SQL will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countS FROM tabl WHERE id LIKE ?
AND
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countS FROM tabl WHERE id LIKE ?
```

I'm pretty sure this cannot work.

The separator between Selects must be `;`. If your DB allows multiple command statements.

If you are using only the keys from the input Map, then better pass only the `keySet()`

Eventually, I would write a single select that will return a single Map: key => count:

```
SELECT 
<foreach collection="dataMap.keySet()" value="key", separator=", ">
<bind name="currentKey" value = 'key + "%"' />
SUM(CASE WHEN id LIKE #{currentKey,jdbcType=VARCHAR} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_${key} 
</foreach>
FROM tabl
```

Of course replace the *CASE WHEN* with the equivalent structure used by your DB dialect.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. `<foreach collection="dataMap" index="key" item="value" open=""
   separator="," close="">
     SUM(CASE WHEN id LIKE #{key,jdbcType=VARCHAR} || '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "${key}"    
    </foreach>`

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11

Comment: Yes, SUM (1 or 0)  instead of COUNT, I've fixed the answer accordingly.